# Can't access Github at all from my home connection

Tags: github

From today in the morning I have a problem : I can't access github at all on any device in my house, any request I try to do finishes in a timeout, for example :

- Trying to `git fetch`, `git pull` or `git push` a repository
- accessing the `https://github.com/` website

However I have no problem accessing the following domains :

- `api.github.com`
- `status.github.com`

When I do a `tracert github.com`, the result is the following :

```
Détermination de l'itinéraire vers github.com [192.30.253.113]
avec un maximum de 30 sauts :

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  livebox.home [192.168.1.1]
  2     *        *        *     Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
  3     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  ae101-0.ncidf204.Paris13eArrondissement.francetelecom.net [193.253.81.6]
  4     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  ae41-0.niidf202.Paris15eArrondissement.francetelecom.net [193.252.98.177]
  5     1 ms     1 ms     2 ms  193.252.137.74
  6     *        *        *     Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
  7   964 ms     *        *     ae-2-4.bear1.Washington111.Level3.net [4.69.210.174]
  8    92 ms    92 ms    92 ms  GITHUB-INC.bear1.Washington111.Level3.net [4.53.116.102]
  9     *        *        *     Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
 10     *        *        *     Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
 11     *        *        *     Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
 12     *        *        *     Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
 13     *        *        *     Délai d'attente de la demande dépassé.
```

I tried desperate solutions :

- Rebooting the internet box
- flushing my DNS cache (but as it is not working on any device, I think it has no effect)

Thanks for helping !

Comment: Can you host a wifi network with your mobile device and connect your desktop to it? So we can start to isolate where the problem is.

Comment: As you asked I shared the connection of my cellhpone via USB on the computer, and Github is displayed correctly ; however this computer does not display Github (as the two other computers of the house) when connected to the WI-FI

Comment: So, looks like either your router or modem (or even your network provider) is doing something to make your life hard. Or they are just having a bad time in their network configuration. You can try other things if possible, like connecting your PC directly (cable) to your router and also to your modem (cable, adsl...). If those work, something is wrong on your PC-WiFi or Router-WiFi configuration.

Comment: When I directly connect my PC to the modem (via cable or via wifi), I can't access the github site, however when I connect my cellphone in 4G and connect my laptop on it, it works great, so yeah I think it's a problem on the router (a Livebox v4 from my internet provider). I think I will call the assistance when I'll have some free time to see if it's not a problem from their side.